# Trying to use apt-get in Kubernetes Node

Tags: linux, apt, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to install the `nfs-common` package via `apt-get` on a Kubernetes node. To achieve this I created a privileged pod and then accessed it with this command: `kubectl exec -ti privileged-pod sh`

Once I'm inside the container shell I execute this command to access the node:

```
chroot /host/
```

Here is where I should be able to use the following: `apt-get install -y nfs-common`

But I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found
```

I tried to download `apt` with `wget`, but `dpkg` is not available either:

```
/bin/sh: dpkg: not found
```

How could I install the package?

Docker for Mac version: v19.03.8

Kubernetes version: v1.15.5

Kubernetes Node OS: Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64

Using docker-desktop node

Comment: The OS you posted, "Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit x86_64" is too broad to determine which flavor of user space (CentOS or Debian or something else) your nodes are running.  Check if there is any output from `cat /etc/*release`, that should indicate which user space flavor you are running.  You may have another package manager installed such as `yum` or `dnf`.

Comment: @GracefulRestart the output for cat /etc/*release is PRETTY_NAME="Docker Desktop"

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to install software in the vm that Docker Desktop is setting up for you.  Even if you could, I doubt the kernel in that environment would support NFS. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want a pod to be able to mount an NFS volume?

Answer (score -1):

Don't install packages on running containers. Never ever. That's not how it is supposed to work.

Even more generally, if you need to log in into a particular node on Kubernetes to do *anything*, you are doing it wrong.

If you do need NFS, make sure to use a Docker image that has it already installed, or install it using a `Dockerfile` to make your own image.